# Where to hold my socket in my redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, socket.io, react-redux

Currently I am using slices and redux-thunks to create my redux store. I am fairly new to redux and I quickly realized that state is not the place to store my socket connection. The socket connection is global and is used by almost all of the components. And most importantly the socket connection needs to stay open, so I can't be making a new connection on each dispatched action.

Any advice, suggestions, or examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets should typically go in a Redux middleware, where they have access to `dispatch` and `getState`:

https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live

Comment: Thanks for that example. Regarding the middleware would that be connected to the store by concatenating it to the default middleware (I am using redux toolkit). So getDefaultMiddleware().concat([socketMiddleWare()])>

Comment: Yup, exactly!  (the extra array around the middleware isn't strictly necessary, but correct otherwise)